# How can I execute a JS function from the top of the stack?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to execute a function from the top of the stack.  That is, any variables defined with "var" should be defined in the global sense.  Is this possible?  fn.call(window) doesn't work.

```
<script>
  var foo = "I am top level foo.";

  var fn = function(){
    var foo = "Setting foo from in a function";
  }

  fn.call(window);  //doesn't work, var is still set locally in fn.
  alert(foo);  //desired effect will alert "setting foo from in a function"
</script>
```

**Please note:**  I am fully aware that not specifying "var" makes an item a global variable.  The problem is that I can not specify the contents of "fn", it is user-defined, but expected to be run from the top level.

I'm willing to use eval if necessary.

Comment: You're saying you want to get this effect without changing the implementation of `fn`? You want `fn` to declare a new local variable and somehow have that overwrite the globally declared `foo`? I'm confused about what it is you're asking.

Comment: Three answers, all deleted because they didn't read the entire question. :-D Maybe you should highlight the important last paragraph.

Comment: @John:  That is untrue.  It was in the original question.

Comment: A little more insight as to what you are trying to achieve would help guide the answers in the right direction....

Comment: @Ian:  Exactly correct.  I'd like fn to be executed as if it were part of top level code.  Or, put another way, I'd like to eval the contents of fn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you cannot overwrite the value of `foo` that way. When you specified `var foo` in the global context, it is attached to the global object (in global scope).

When you then specified `var foo` within your function, you declared it within the scope of that function. This means that it is unknown to the outside world<sup>+</sup>. What you could do, is something like this:

```
var fn = function() {
   this.foo = "Setting foo from in a function";
};
```

Or to be more explicit:

```
var fn = function() {
  window.foo = "Setting foo from in a function";
};
```

Is this what you want?

<sup>+</sup> When you defined `foo` inside the function, it was attached to the **Activation object** and not the **Global object**. Every time you enter the execution context for a function, a new **Activation object** is created. So every time you call the function, you're getting a new `foo`. This is just as well, otherwise you wouldn't be able to create variables that are local in scope to the function; they would leak into the global context.

**UPDATE**

I guess you could do something like the following if you really want to evaluate code inside a function in a global context. It's ugly, and I'm not sure why you'd want to do it, but here goes:

```
var foo = 2;

var fn = function() {
   var foo = 3;
}

console.log(foo); //prints 2

var fnSource = fn.toSource();
eval(fnSource.replace(/^\(function\s*\(\)\s*{/, "").replace(/}\s*\)$/, ""));

console.log(foo); //prints 3
```

This will strip out `(function () {` and `})` so that you end up with only the code in the middle, which you then run through `eval`.

Once again, I have to stress that I don't recommend doing this.

Comment: I am aware of how scope works, and I believe you grasp what I am trying to do.  Just to be sure:  Are you saying there is absolutely no way to execute a function in global space?

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate the code that is inside a function in the global context?

Comment: @Vivin:  That's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Sambo: I've updated my solution. It should do what you want to do, as crazy as it sounds :)

Comment: I was just coding this up myself after finding out about toSource().  Great work, and thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sambo no problem. But like I already mentioned, this is a maintenance nightmare on many different levels. It also can be a source of all kinds of insidious bugs and it is pretty unmaintainable and fragile. You have been warned! :)

Comment: @Vivin:  Yep, I'm well aware of that.  I'm just doing some experimentation.  toSource()/toString() was what I was looking for.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is asking too much. Local variables are just that: local. They are created in a local scope to the function and are not exported outside of the call. As a caller you simply cannot see them as they are not stored in any type of hash or namespace or object that you can access.

Your best bet is to get the user to modify their function.

I suppose, barring that, you could jump through rings of fire and do some string search-and-replaces on the function's `toSource()` source code and remove the `var` keywords. Or take the `toSource()`, remove the `function {` ... `}` wrappings, and then `eval()` that code. That *might* work. But that's an inordinate amount of runaround, very brittle, and major code smell.

---

If you *can* get the function modified then the solution is simple. If you get rid of the `var` then you will modify the global variable. The purpose of `var` is specifically to create local variables, so just don't use it and you're there.

```
var fn = function() {
    foo = "Setting foo from in a function";
}
```

If you want to explicitly affect the global scope then modify the `window` object which is the container for global objects:

```
var fn = function() {
    window.foo = "Setting foo from in a function";
}
```

Comment: toSource()?  Now we are onto something!  Can't I just eval() toSource?

Comment: @Sambo Sure can -- check out my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `var`, set the variables inside of the `this` object.  That way, if you call the function with `window`, you'll be setting the "global" variables:

```
window.foo = "I am top level foo.";

var fn = function(){
    this.foo = "Setting foo from in a function";
}

fn.call(window);
alert(foo);
```

You can then also call the function with a different context as well:

```
var anObject = { foo: "Initial Value" };
fn.call(anObject);
alert(anObject.foo); // Will be the modified value
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I cannot alter the contents of fn.  That includes changing any variable instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this effect without changing `fn`, but this code is not for the faint of heart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gFoo = "";

var fn = function() {
    var foo = "Setting foo from in a function";
}

var fnText = fn.toString();
var newFunction = fnText.substring(0, fnText.length - 1) + "gFoo = foo; }";

eval("var x = " + newFunction + "; x();");
alert(gFoo);
</script>
```